# How do I install a Python module with a different name than the catkin package?

Tags: ros, python, catkin, module

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My package is named **camera_info_manager_py**, but the Python module is **camera_info_manager**.

With **rosbuild** that was easy: just create a `src/camera_info_manager.py` script, and dependent packages could import it directly.

With **catkin** I can't figure out how to make it work. For API compatibility with earlier releases, I prefer *not* to rename the module **camera_info_manager_py** (which does work).

I suppose I could add that module to the **camera_info_manager** package, and make **camera_info_manager_py** depend on it for compatibility. But, that would be a hassle, and not relevant to the many users of the C++ **camera_info_manager** package.

**EDIT**: Thanks, William. I had tried the **py_modules**, and as you noted, it did not work. I didn't realize that was caused by a missing feature.

I do not fully understand your recommended work-around. Would the script go in **src/camera_info_manager.py**, as it did before? I was not able to figure out how to resolve that in the PYTHONPATH.

For compatibility, other packages need to do this:

```
import camera_info_manager
cinfo = camera_info_manager.CameraInfoManager()
```

or:

```
from camera_info_manager import *
cinfo = CameraInfoManager()
```

I still don't see how to make that happen.

**EDIT2**: I did (almost) exactly as you recommended, but catkin installs no **camera_info_manager** package.

```
$ roscd
$ catkin_make
$ cd build
$ make install
$ ls -l ../install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 3 joq joq 4096 Mar 26 16:59 ackermann_msgs
-rw-rw-r-- 1 joq joq  421 Mar 26 16:59 camera_info_manager_py-0.2.0.egg-info
drwxrwxr-x 2 joq joq 4096 Mar 26 16:59 unique_id
-rw-rw-r-- 1 joq joq  276 Mar 26 16:59 unique_id-1.0.1.egg-info
drwxr-xr-x 3 joq joq 4096 Mar 26 16:59 uuid_msgs
```

So, there is an egg-info for **camera_info_manager_py**, but no Python package.

```
$ make run_tests_camera_info_manager_py
-- run_tests.py: execute commands
  /opt/ros/groovy/bin/rostest --pkgdir=/home/joq/ros/wet/groovy/src/camera_info_manager_py --package=camera_info_manager_py --results-filename tests_unit_test.xml /home/joq/ros/wet/groovy/src/camera_info_manager_py/tests/unit_test.test
... logging to /home/joq/.ros/log/rostest-vision-4-5760.log
[ROSUNIT] Outputting test results to /home/joq/ros/wet/groovy/build/test_results/camera_info_manager_py/rostest-tests_unit_test.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joq/ros/wet/groovy/src/camera_info_manager_py/tests/test_camera_info_manager.py", line 17, in <module>
    from camera_info_manager import *
ImportError: No module named camera_info_manager
testtest_camera_info_manager_py ... FAILURE!
```

As you can see, the `from camera_info_manager import *` fails.

The only difference with what you recommended is that my `src/camera_info_manager/__init__.py` contains only this:

```
from .camera_info_manager import *
```

I did it that way because the **camera_info_manager** module was already careful not to define anything not needed by its users. I guess it is equivalent to putting the entire script inside ****init**.py**.

**EDIT3**: here's my current setup.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

d = generate_distutils_setup(
    py_modules=['camera_info_manager'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    install_requires=['yaml'],
    )

setup(**d)
```

**EDIT4**: yes, the install did show these errors:

```
+ cd /home/joq/ros/wet/groovy/src/camera_info_manager_py
+ /usr/bin/env PYTHONPATH=/home/joq/ros/wet/groovy/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/joq/ros/wet/groovy/build/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/joq/ros/wet/groovy/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages CATKIN_BINARY_DIR=/home/joq/ros/wet/groovy/build /usr/bin/python /home/joq/ros/wet/groovy/src/camera_info_manager_py/setup.py build --build-base /home/joq/ros/wet/groovy/build/camera_info_manager_py install --install-layout=deb --prefix=/home/joq/ros/wet/groovy/install --install-scripts=/home/joq/ros/wet/groovy/install/bin
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running build
running build_py
file src/camera_info_manager.py (for module camera_info_manager) not found
file src/camera_info_manager.py (for module camera_info_manager) not found
running install
running install_lib
warning: install_lib: '/home/joq/ros/wet/groovy/build/camera_info_manager_py/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7' does not exist -- no Python modules to install
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59163/how-do-i-install-a-python-module-with-a-different-name-than-the-catkin-package?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-03-26**:
Is your repository up-to-date? https://github.com/jack-oquin/camera_info_manager_py/blob/master/setup.py Or is this an old setup.py

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-26**:
That is the old one. I have not committed these changes, because they don't work. The github one (which works) provides the **camera_info_manager_py** name, instead.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-26**:
I could commit them to a new branch, if you want to experiment with it.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-03-26**:
Your setup.py should be `packages=['camera_info_manager']` not `py_modules=['camera_info_manager']`. Can you post the output from `catkin_make install`? I bet it has a message about not finding a py_module 'camera_info_manager'.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-26**:
Changing it to packages worked! Now the tests run successfully, and the `src/camera_info_manager` directory contents get installed under dist-packages. Thanks for the help, William!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can tell the `setup.py` to install individual modules rather than packages:

http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-individual-modules

A setup.py for your example might look like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

d = generate_distutils_setup(
    py_modules=['camera_info_manager'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'}
)

setup(**d)
```

When I was testing this I noticed that `catkin` warns:

```
*** Arguments ['py_modules'] to setup() not supported in catkin devel space in setup.py of camera_info_manager_py
```

This indicates to me that we never implemented support for this argument in devel spaces. We should support this, so I opened a ticket:

https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/399

For now that means that if you want your package to work in the devel space then you should wrap it in a python package, and you can transparently do this using the package `__all__` magic variable.

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package

UPDATE:

Your current layout is:

```
src/
  camera_info_manager.py
```

And your setup.py might be:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

d = generate_distutils_setup(
    py_modules=['camera_info_manager'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'}
)

setup(**d)
```

I would propose that you change your layout to this:

```
src/
  camera_info_manager/
    __init__.py
    camera_info_manager.py
```

And in the **init**.py:

```
from .camera_info_manager import CameraInfoManager, etc...
__all__ = ['CameraInfoManager', 'free_func1', 'another_class']
```

Users will still be able to do this:

```
import camera_info_manager
cinfo = camera_info_manager.CameraInfoManager()
```

Or

```
from camera_info_manager import *
cinfo = CameraInfoManager()
```

But they will also be able to do this:

```
from camera_info_manager.camera_info_manager import CameraInfoManager
cinfo = CameraInfoManager()
```

And your setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

d = generate_distutils_setup(
    packages=['camera_info_manager'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'}
)

setup(**d)
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7